# Why spacemacs would like to control this computer using accessibility feature on OSX?

Tags: spacemacs, osx

When I start up spacemacs it prompts for the privileged to be granted?

[image]

Why spacemacs needs to request this?

Comment: Can you confirm that ordinary Emacs (without Spacemacs) does *not* do this? (e.g. running `emacs -Q`).